# CSS — Firefox giving completley different interpretation to Chrome/Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox

Hi
I'm really at a loss as to why Firefox is rendering my page so *wrong*

[Link to problem page](http://tomdarracott.com/2011) (not live yet)

In Chrome and Safari, it works as it should. Plus, the HTML validates, no jquery errors.
Usually FF is not that far off. However, yes, the contrcution of the framework is pretty complex. I'm nesting a lot of divs, and utilising the

> display:table

and

> display:table-cell

properties. Sizes of images are all based on parents too. It's basically a super fluid centred layout with the added bonus of the image size being fluid too (i'm trying something new here, so maybe it serves me right)

I'm guessing and hoping that there is probably just one, stupid thing that Firefox does not interpret in the same way. Hoping someone might shed some light for me. Much appreciated

Comment: Yikes! That is quite different.

Comment: Weird no? It's one of those situtions where i dont know where to begin to start looking for the problem! Especially when the html validates and there are no script errors.

Comment: Fixed: http://www.joshuacarmody.com/temp/Tom%20Darracott.htm . See my answer below as to why this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with your code a bit, and it seems like Firefox doesn't support `position: relative` in combination with `display: table-cell` or `display: table`. Therefore, your positioning context wasn't getting reset, and the absolutely-positioned images were being scaled relative to the width of the window, instead of the width of their container. I changed this...

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img width="100%" height="auto" alt="image" src="images/2.png"></div>
    <!-- Snip -->
</div>
```

...to this...

```
<div class="imgContainer">
    <div style="position: relative;">
        <div class="thumbnail"><img width="100%" height="auto" alt="image" src="images/2.png"></div>
        <!-- Snip -->
    </div>
</div>
```

...and it started looking a lot more like the Chrome version. Basically you need an intermediate div with `position: relative` in-between your table-cell and your absolutely  positioned thumbnails to reset the positioning context. This is the cause of the giant images, at least.

**EDIT:**

Here, I [fixed it for you](http://www.joshuacarmody.com/temp/Tom%20Darracott.htm). Be sure to remove the <BASE> tag in the header if you use this source file.

Comment: Cant thank you enough, that fixed it completely. I was sure that there was soe little thing that would fix it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You are using CSS for idealogical reasons. Any sensible person would use a table.

Comment: Lol... you are so right. Ok, I'm going to make some tables. BRB

Comment: Hmm, although i take that back... change the size of the browser window, divs float left and expand at certain browser size markers set in jquery, i dont think i can do this with tables right? Thats why i originally went for divs. Correct me if I'm wrong about that functionality though, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you using a table for that? It's only bad to use tables to layout your web site structure. For your purposes that is exactly what was designed for.

It also looks like you're using inline style in your html. Why aren't you using a stylesheet and classes? I thought we cleared this all up in my answer to your last question?

Comment: Hmmm, could try... but css... thats in a css file?! (Sorry angry cat!)

Comment: @RGBK, I'm not sure where you got angry from, I didn't mean to make it sound like that. If you're talking about my last sentence I remember giving you a link to the yahoo developer best practices page, and was wondering why after reading it you were still writing CSS inline.

Answer (score 0):

Well...  `.tableMaker > .imgContainer > .thumbnail` having a width of 100% is partly culprit, it seems to me.  Switch them to a set value, not percents. (that style is in html, not css, fyi)

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that style is in HTML not css? Agree it must be this 100% thing. But if it works in webkit, it should just work. Grr. Will keep at it.

Comment: @Philip Sheard I disagree.  Using CSS he could place them in ANY format visibly, not just in columns and rows.  He's just overcomplicated his CSS and not fully understood what he's doing.

Comment: @RGBK I just mean you are setting your width to 100% in your html code, like `<img width="100%"/>` and that I wasn't referring to css styles. I wrote that statement because I used a selector syntax that css uses to clarify which element I was talking about.

Comment: In Chrome, at least, the width="100%" in the img tag is causing the thumbnails to scale with the window size (load the example URL in Chrome and then shrink/grow the window). I think the effect is kinda cool, and I can see why he'd want to replicate it in Firefox.

Comment: @joshua thats another bug i'm going to look into though with Chrome: it flickers when i scale it down. In safari it's as smooth as silk. For another post or a google seacrh once i sort this FF issue

Answer (score 0):

For some reason firefox is choking on the 100% value for your images, like here: `<img width="100%"` If you explicitly set this value it seems to work.